# Why is it enough to imply that $x^3+x+1|x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I tried to understand a solution but I am stuck at how did the solution concluded that $x^3+x+1\mid x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1.$

Consider the field of element $8$ given by $\mathbb{F}=\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[X]}{\langle X^3+X+1\rangle}.$ Now I can tell that each element $x$ in $\mathbb{F}$ satisfies the relation $x^8-x=0.$ Also I can see that $X^8-X=X(X-1)(X^6+X^5+X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1).$ The solution then says this implies that $X^3+X+1\mid X^6+X^5+X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1.$ However I do not understand how did they reach such conclusion?

I can see that $X^8-X$ can be factored into $\Pi _{i=1}^8X-q_i$ for every $q_i\in\mathbb{F}$ but I do not see how that would help to solve my problem.

Comment: You can’t assert that $\mathbb F$ is a field until you know that $X^3+X+1$ is prime. But the know that $X^{2^3}-X$ is the product of all the prime polynomials of degrees which divide $3.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f = x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2,\,$ being a cubic with no roots. So $\,\Bbb F_2[x]/f $ is a field $\,\Bbb F_8$ with $8$ elements.  Generalizing [Fermat's little Theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) in a finite field field $\Bbb F_q\,$ of size $\,q,\,$ all elements$\neq 0$ form a group of order $\,q\!-\!1\,$ so, by [Lagrange's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) $\,a^{q-1} = 1\,$ for all $\,0\ne a\in\Bbb F_q$

In particular, for $\,q=p^m\,$ we have $\,x^{q-1}\! = 1\,$ in $\,\Bbb F_q\cong \Bbb F_p[x]/f\ $ so $\,f\mid x^{q-1}\!-1\,$ in $\,\Bbb F_p[x].$

So in OP we have $\,f\mid x^7-1 = (x\!-\!1)g\,$ and $\,\underbrace{(x\!-\!1,f)=1}_{\large {\rm by}\ f(1)\neq 0\ \,{\rm in}\,\ \Bbb F_2}\Rightarrow\,f\mid g\,$ by Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: Hi Bill, your answer is perfectly what I am looking for. It is really concise and clear, thank you so much!

Comment: Just a small question, was there a typo in here $\,f\mid x^{q-1}\!-1\,$ in $\,\Bbb F_q[x].$ Should this not in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ instead since we were focusing on breaking it down in $\mathbb{F}_2$ rather than $\mathbb{F}_8$?

Comment: @JustWandering Yes, now fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the general result is that the elements of $\Bbb F_q$, $q=p^n$ with $p$ prime, satisfy $x^q-x=0$. Moreover, $x^q-x$ is the product of all irreducible polynomials of degree $d\geq 1$ over $\Bbb F_p$ with $d\mid n$.

In your case, $q=2^3$ and $x^8-x = x(x-1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$ over $\Bbb F_2$.